# Flutter How to display Chips text on the screen when Chip's pressed?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Was Wondering how could i display the text that is within the Chip on the screen when the user taps on the chip, would like the text to be below the Chip, and when the user presses the chips and the words display and there is no horizontal space than the word should go on a new line below.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';
import 'package:femija_musliman/rendit_fjalet_quiz.dart';

import 'dataset.dart';

class RenditFjaletButton extends StatefulWidget {
  RenditFjaletButton({required this.QuizList, Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  late List QuizList;

  @override
  State<RenditFjaletButton> createState() => _RenditFjaletButtonState();
}

class _RenditFjaletButtonState extends State<RenditFjaletButton> {
  late Future<List<QuizInfo>?> futureData;

  int counter = 1;
  int counterForChips = 0;
  bool showWord = true;
  int _selectedChipsIndex = 0;
  List selectReportList = [];

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureData = fetchData1() as Future<List<QuizInfo>?>;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            toolbarHeight: 23.h,
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEF6E98),
            title: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 50),
                  child: Text(
                    'Rendit Fjalet',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.sp),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 60, bottom: 60),
                    child: Text(
                      '- Fjala numer:  -',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.sp),
                    ),
                  ))
            ])),
        body: FutureBuilder<List<QuizInfo>?>(
            future: futureData,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<QuizInfo>? data = snapshot.data;
                return Stack(children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage(
                              'assets/background.PNG',
                            ),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: Wrap(
                        direction: Axis.horizontal,
                        spacing: 20,
                        children: List<Widget>.generate(widget.QuizList.length,
                            (int index) {
                          var chipsText = widget.QuizList[index].toString();

                          void _handleTap(int index) {
                            setState(() {
                              _selectedChipsIndex = index;
                            });
                          }

                          return GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                _handleTap(index);
                              },
                              child: Chip(
                                label: Text(
                                  chipsText,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20.sp,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                                backgroundColor: Color(0xFF50CFFD),
                              ));
                        }),
                      )),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 170, left: 40),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        " ${(widget.QuizList[_selectedChipsIndex])}",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.sp,
                            color: Color(0xFF50CFFD),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 155),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                        child: Divider(
                          endIndent: 30,
                          thickness: 5,
                          color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ]);
              }
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }));
  }
}
```

So the image is what i want to achieve right now i only have the chips with words on them, i want to when the user presses the chip i want the word within the chip to display at and when there is no horizontal space the text displays on a new line ][click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqKWg.png)

Comment: Can you show me the image which you wanna achieve?

Comment: Yup added an image and a description of it

Comment: if I'm not wrong you are trying to do, when you press on chip, text will be show below the chip and within text on the chip? am I right

Comment: yeah so lets say we have five chips, five of them having text in them, if the user presses any of them the chips text will display below, and if the user presses the other chips the other chips text will show without overriding the first

Comment: Okay ,now I have understood your requirement, check my updated answer. I think you won't be disappointed this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I'm not wrong , you're achieving [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPY7B.jpg):

I just Create new list with same model type and add item, if that item is selected .

```
class QuizInfo {
  String? title;
  bool visible;
  QuizInfo({required this.title, this.visible = false});
}



class RenditFjaletButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const RenditFjaletButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RenditFjaletButton> createState() => _RenditFjaletButtonState();
}

class _RenditFjaletButtonState extends State<RenditFjaletButton> {
  late Future<List<QuizInfo>?> futureData;

  List<QuizInfo> selectReportList = [];

  List<QuizInfo> quizList = [
    QuizInfo(
      title: "Twitter",
    ),
    QuizInfo(
      title: "Instagram",
    ),
    QuizInfo(title: "Facebook"),
    QuizInfo(title: "Stackoverflow"),
    QuizInfo(title: "Github"),
  ];

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureData = fetchData1() as Future<List<QuizInfo>?>;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            toolbarHeight: 23,
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFEF6E98),
            title: Column(children: const [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 50),
                  child: Text(
                    'Rendit Fjalet',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 60, bottom: 60),
                    child: Text(
                      '- Fjala numer:  -',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ))
            ])),
        body: Stack(children: [
          Container(
            decoration: const  BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(
                      'assets/background.PNG',
                    ),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover)),
          ),
          Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Wrap(
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                spacing: 20,
                children: List<Widget>.generate(quizList.length, (int index) {
                  var chipsText = quizList[index].title.toString();

                  return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          quizList[index].visible = !(quizList[index].visible);
                          if (quizList[index].visible) {
                            selectReportList.add(quizList[index]);
                          } else {
                            selectReportList.remove(quizList[index]);
                            selectReportList.join(', ');
                          }
                        });
                      },
                      child: Chip(
                        label: Text(
                          chipsText,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        backgroundColor: quizList[index].visible
                            ? Colors.pinkAccent
                            : const Color(0xFF50CFFD),
                      ));
                }),
              )),

          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 170, left: 40),
            child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Wrap(
                              direction: Axis.horizontal,
                              spacing: 20,
                              children: List<Widget>.generate(
                                  selectReportList.length, (int index) {
                                return Text(
                                  " ${(selectReportList[index].title)}",
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      color: Color(0xFF50CFFD),
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                );
                              })),
                          Divider(
                            endIndent: 30,
                            thickness: 5,
                            color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            selectReportList.clear();
                            
                          });
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.cancel,
                          color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                        ))
                  ],
                )),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Just need to implement this on my code if you dont mind

Comment: ill edit the question and put the whole code of the screen so its easier for you

Comment: here updated the code

Comment: My pleasure, You may follow me on  linkedIn or instagram with same username.

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable called something like chipText, and then on this part

```
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
            chipText = widget.QuizList[index].toString()
            },
```

Create a new Text widget (or any other you want the tapped text to be displayed) in your Stack children's list.

After it, set the state, or whatever state management way you are using your app.

Comment: tried that and it doesnt work i think it needs to be something with like a bool variable for it to display

Comment: You can add an empty Container, and when cipText is declared by tapping on the chip, setState will update the Container and display the text. Otherwise, please explain more in detail your question.